# JBPM Tasks - Stuck in Created State - Not moving to Ready State

Tags: workflow, jbpm, kie

We are using JBPM 7.5 for the past two years without much issues and more than 200000 workflows are successfully processed by JBPM.

Suddenly, we are experiencing one new issue, where every newly created task is stuck in the "Created" state and not becoming "Ready" state. While checking the [documentation](https://docs.jbpm.org/7.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_kie.ksrestapi), the following is mentioned

> *A newly created task starts in the "Created" stage. Usually, it will then automatically become "Ready", after which the task will show up on the task list of all the actors that are allowed to execute the task.*

Now the problem here is that what does the word "***Usually***" mean here?, I am not able to find any reference anywhere related to this. What are the causes for a task to be stuck in "*Created*" state?